# Jupyter notebook, plots appearing twice

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I'm running some example code from a tutorial on making animated plots. It works, but instead of just the one animated plot, I get two in my Jupyter notebook: an animated plot and a snapshot of the (beginning? end?) animation. Why is this happening, any ideas?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim(( 0, 2))
ax.set_ylim((-2, 2))

line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return (line,)

def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return (line,)


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=100, interval=20, 
                               blit=True)

HTML(anim.to_jshtml())
```

This is what the output looks like in Jupyter notebooks:

[image]

Comment: Try adding semicolon `HTML(anim.to_jshtml());`.